# Convert Date from String in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting from my server a date as string like this **"10/4/2013 10:00:00 PM"**. Now I want only hours to display in my label.But the problem is am using the below code but not getting actual time.

```
-(NSString*)convert:(NSString*)strdate
{

    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
   [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString:strdate];


    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
    NSString *depResult = [df stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"hours  %@ ", [df stringFromDate:date]);

    return depResult;
}
```

and am giving String input as **"10/4/2013 9:00:00 PM"** and getting output as **"05:30"**.Please correct me where am doing wrong.Thanks

Comment: You're in India, I suspect.  What's the timezone offset in India?

Comment: Please do not use fixed date formats, use [`NSDateFormatterStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDateFormatterStyle)

Comment: hi friends if i want to set for UTC then what zone i have to give @AnoopVaidya

Comment: You're reading in UTC and displaying in local time.  NSLog your NSDate object and it will show the UTC time you read.

Comment: Also `[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];` here `HH` should be `hh`

Comment: @rckoenes - If the date string is coming from a "service" then one MUST use a fixed date format.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, when you parsing form string to date yes, but when formatting a date to string it is better to use the `NSDateFormatterStyle` so that the date will be presented in a way the user wants it to be.

Comment: @rckoenes - Only if the programmer wants the format to change based on the user's whims.

Comment: @HotLicks True and any smart developer will use the `NSDateFormatterStyle`. Since most people in the world use `day-month-year` and not `month/day/year` this may cause sone problem when having a dat like `1-2-2014` and I said that is better to use, not that you most use it.

Comment: @rckoenes You can completely ignore formatting styles. They are kind of limited and have problems on some locales. It's better to generate a style from template (`+[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:]`).

Answer (score 11):

```
+(NSString *)getDateStringFromDate :(NSDate *)date {
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return dateString;
}

+(NSDate *)getDateFromDateString :(NSString *)dateString {
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have this date        `"10/4/2013 9:00:00 pm"` from server,

and you want the same to be in India time, if your desired output is `02:24 AM`

Then you need to do something like this.

```
-(NSString*)convert:(NSString*)strdate
{

    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString:strdate];


    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSString *depResult = [df stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"hours  %@ ", [df stringFromDate:date]);

    return depResult;
}
```

Comment: hi @Anoop Vaidya its not only for india i want it for universal can u pls help me?and thanks for your answer

Comment: this will work for any country and your locale is `systemlocale`... you need to remoe the timeZoneForSec... to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
- (NSString *)convert:(NSString *)strdate
{
    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString:strdate];


    NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
    NSString * depResult = [df stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"hours  %@ ", [df stringFromDate:date]);

    return depResult;
}
```

Comment: I guess `en_US_POSIX ` is not needed.

Comment: It isn't, but it recommended to use fixed locale, when you are working with fixed-format dates. ``en_US_POSIX`` is best locale to choose.

Comment: what about systemLocale?

Comment: It differs across different machines.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - `en_US_POSIX` definitely is needed, if you plan to "hard-wire" the 12/24 setting.  Otherwise iOS may not honor your 12/24 format setting.